# I need Help to get My Bootstrap Gallery Working using prettyPhoto

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I will appreciate your help in setting up my gallery for my Bootstrap site. I'm following the process on this link but can't get it working: untame.net/2013/02/twitter-bootstrap-build-a-responsive-lightbox-gallery/

My HTML code is on this link: http://texasconnectionferries.com/test/index.txt as I can't post it here due to character limitation. Please, check the 'Gallery' section.

And this is the link to the site so that you can see how is working through the 'Gallery' menu: http://texasconnectionferries.com/test.

I will appreciate every help received.

Much thanks and regards

Segun.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the JS for prettyPhoto.

If you inspect the page using your browser's inspect/developer tools you will see that you have a javascript error

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function`